# A rather strange occurrence with pylab:

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I typed in my IDLE (python 2.7.8 Windows 64bit) the following line after importing pylab as pl:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.ndarray([3,2,1])
```

producing this:

```
array([[[  7.89725907e-316],
        [  7.83323137e-316]],

       [[  1.52244036e-316],
        [  8.00633853e-316]],

       [[  8.59792562e-316],
        [  8.20678215e-316]]])
```

Why has this happened?

Answer (score 2):

`ndarray` is the class underlying numpy arrays. It's not meant to call to construct arrays. Use `pl. array([3, 2, 1])` instead.

The `ndarray` docstring says:

> ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
>           strides=None, order=None)
>
> An array object represents a multidimensional, homogeneous array of
>   fixed-size items.  An associated data-type object describes the format
>   of each element in the array (its byte-order, how many bytes it
>   occupies in memory, whether it is an integer, a floating point number,
>   or something else, etc.)
>
> Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty` (refer
>   to the See Also section below).  The parameters given here refer to a
>   low-level method (`ndarray(...)`) for instantiating an array.